# Android SQLite выборка суммы за месяц

Tags: android, sqlite, select

Даты хранятся в миллисекундах. 
Хочу вывести сумму например за март:
db.rawQuery

```
SELECT SUM(col_name) 
FROM (table_name) 
WHERE strftime('%m', col_date) = '03' AND strftime('%Y', col_date) = '2019'
```

Но курсор не выводит ничего, аналогичные запросы без условия `WHERE` работают.

Не могу понять где ошибка.

Comment: если время в timestamp, то это нужно явно указать, так как по умолчанию ожидается дата в "человеческом" формате (как 2019-03-23) - `strftime('%m', col_date, unixepoch)`. Так же timestamp - это количество **секунд** с 1970 года (то есть вам нужно преобразовать ваши милисекунды). Есть [документация](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) и там все написано.

Comment: Для наглядности покажите сами данные а так же структуру таблицы.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо, pavlofff.
Действительно достаточно было указать 'unixepoch' и использовать секунды вместо миллисекунд:

```
SELECT SUM(col_name) 
FROM (table_name) 
WHERE strftime('%m', col_date, unixepoch) = '03' AND 
strftime('%Y', col_date, unixepoch) = '2019'
```

В таком варианте все работает.